# why output is 0 here. i am a newbie (20 days experience)

Tags: arrays, c, function, sum, arguments

*i want to copy inputed array in sum_of_elements function as argument and then sum all the elements of array, but i am getting output 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i, num, sum;
int sum_of_elements(int arr[]) {
  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    for (i = 0; sum = 0, i < num; i++) {
      sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
int main() {
  printf("enter number of digits you want to add\n");
  scanf("%d", & num);

  int arr[num];

  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    printf("enter number %d\n", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", & arr[i]);
  }
  int total = sum_of_elements(arr);
  printf("%d", total);

  return 0;
```

Comment: Because you are setting `sum = 0` after every iteration. (also, the outer loop is useless)

Comment: Besides @CherryDT's remarks, it's also better to make `i` and `sum` local variables to the `sum_of_elements` function and to pass `num` as a function argument. Don't use global variables, until you understand when it's convenient to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line of code:

```
for (i = 0; sum = 0, i < num; i++) {
```

This resets `sum` to 0 *every loop*.

It should be

```
for (i = 0, sum = 0; i < num; i++) {
```

But it's probably better to do this:

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the double for loop in your sum_of_elements function.

Removing the extra for loop, resolves the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i, num, sum;
int sum_of_elements(int arr[]) {
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
int main() {
    
    
      printf("enter number of digits you want to add\n");
      scanf("%d", & num);
    
      int arr[num];
    
      for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("enter number %d\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
      }
      int total = sum_of_elements(arr);
      printf("%d", total);
    
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: u didnt do sum=0 before for loop.